# Image to Svg-path

Tags: android, svg, photoshop, adobe-illustrator, gimp

I am trying to create svg paths from a png file using gimp and following this tutorial :  http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/04/26/how-to-create-svg-paths-easily-using-the-gimp/

I am trying to use this https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AwesomeSplash as a splash screen for an android app but with a different image. I can't seem to get the right path for the image using the tutorial above.

I tried to display the svg path from the tutorial website, which is the path for the cut out rectangle TV, and this is what I get

[image]  [image] [image] [image]

Above, the yellow color should be filling up the small black square but its somehow creating a border outside of it and filling that up. Using the splash screen from ViksaaSkool ( https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AwesomeSplash) I am trying to display the letters U 5 + (underlined) in place of the android logo.

[image] [image]

Comment: The right tool to edit SVGs is [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/). It's free too. SVG editing support in Gimp is only for the shapes themselves, and doesn't cover their rendering.

Answer (score 1):

cv14. I use Gimp because is free although is pretty hard to use.

When you export a path you the resulting height and width match with the image size. I know, it is an awful feature of Gimp.

I recommend you to use the paths tool to draw curves because you will control the direction. You could get undesirables results when you fill a shape. Could you check this site out?: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-svg-fill-rule-property/

As well as I recommend you split the image in as many paths as possible (All paths will be in the same svg). So you will have better control of what happen.

When you export, you only can select one path to convert to a SVG file. I know, it is an awful feature of Gimp. But you can merge all SVG file in one using some plain text editor.

Coming back to the svg tutorial: Using Gimp: Try to check what you have in the path section before export the path.

If you follow the tutorial omit the part when the author inverts the selection, because you are selecting all less the tv windows. When you invert the selection you have 2 draws in the same path.

The frame

> M 495.00,0.00
> C 495.00,0.00 495.00,417.00 495.00,417.00
> 495.00,417.00 0.00,417.00 0.00,417.00
> 0.00,417.00 0.00,0.00 0.00,0.00
> 0.00,0.00 495.00,0.00 495.00,0.00 Z

And the tv windows:

> M 81.18,219.39
> C 75.28,224.66 73.26,233.55 71.61,241.00
> 68.81,256.26 68.66,271.70 71.61,287.00
> 72.76,294.37 74.47,301.98 79.68,307.70
> 85.29,313.85 91.52,314.81 99.00,316.73
> 99.00,316.73 126.00,321.96 126.00,321.96
> 126.00,321.96 134.00,321.96 134.00,321.96
> 134.00,321.96 144.00,323.00 144.00,323.00
> 156.04,323.14 168.13,322.58 180.00,320.39
> 187.27,319.04 193.58,317.17 198.20,310.91
> 202.27,305.40 200.54,300.30 201.28,294.00
> 201.28,294.00 202.00,244.00 202.00,244.00
> 201.98,234.15 201.61,228.06 192.91,221.85
> 187.58,218.04 176.56,216.51 170.00,215.41
> 153.07,212.57 126.99,210.70 110.00,212.28
> 101.11,213.56 88.05,213.25 81.18,219.39 Z

So coming back with what you would want to do:
In Gimp: you would create a new Image
You should Draw U 5 +  (underlined).
and using the path tool you should Draw your curves in **clockwise** direction.
You should Merge all SVG outcoming.
And finally, you should import the svg in Android.

Comment: Thank you for that. What exactly do you mean "Draw your curves in clockwise direction" ?

Comment: Clockwise or Dextrorotation means moving in the direction of the hands on a clock. The opposite direction is called counterclockwise or anticlockwise or levorotation. It's easy to get confused. When you draw in clockwise, lets suppose you are drawing a clock, you will first insert some arbitrary point, for example in the '6',  and then the next point to accomplish the fill rule property will be at '7', and then the '8' and so on.

Comment: Remember when you are drawing with points, less points are better always. Master the technique will took a while. Another tip: The secret is " use the tangent arms of each point with wisdom".